# MarkLogic unfiltered diacritic search is not working as expected

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using ML 8.

`unfiltered cts:search` is not working as expected for `diacritic` `cts:query`.

Find the below example.

I have inserted the below xml in ML DB with uri `/diacritic/a.xml`

```
<root>
    <name>öily</name>
</root>
```

`cts:search` query which I am running.

```
cts:search(
    doc('/diacritic/a.xml'),
    cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('name'), 'oily', ('diacritic-sensitive')),
    'unfiltered'
)
```

Above cts:query is returning me the above doc but it should not return as `diacritic-sensitive` option is present.

For `filtered` search it is working fine.

Note: `fast diacritic sensitive searches` is set to true

Please help.

Comment: Please also post what your collation(s) is set to for the database. Your query is assuming a default which is either set on the database itself or using MarkLogic's default collation. Knowing this will help people shape an appropriate answer.

Comment: I am not sure where I can set the collation for a database. `fn:default-collation` has returned me `http://marklogic.com/collation/` please let me know if this is correct or you need more detail on the same.

Comment: I think you need to have a look at this section to understand collations and how it affects search resolution: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/encodings_collations  I am not posting this as an answer as it may not be the issue. But I think you need some of the background here to investigate and report on the above.

Answer (score 1):

Collations are irrelevant for search (except for range queries).

The issue here is how indexing works. The keys do not know that they are diacritic-insensitive keys, they only know what the characters in the key are. To compute the diacritic-insensitive key for a word, we remove diacritics and form a key from what is left. To compute the diacritic-sensitive key for a word, we don't remove the diacritics and form a key from the word with them intact.

In this case diacritic-insensitive-key(oily) = diacritic-sensitive-ke(oily) = diacritic-insensitive-key(öily) != diacritic-sensitive-key(öily).

So the index can't resolve the difference here. A diacritic-sensitive search for öily would not match oily in the index, but the reverse is not true.

To get an accurate result here, you'll need to filter.

Addendum: why don't we include the diacritic-sensitivity into the key? Because that would drastically increase the size of the index (x2 for diacritics, x2 more for case).